# What will happen to Parker Solar Probe in the long term?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, trajectory, parker-solar-probe, planetary-protection

Will the probe be intentionally crashed anywhere? Or is keeping space decontaminated not an issue here since temperature and radiation will sterilize anything in that kind of orbit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Surface contamination is not an issue for Mercury or Venus. It is only considered a [Category I (Mercury) or II (Venus)](https://planetaryprotection.nasa.gov/about-categories/) risk, which essentially means don't worry about it too much. Also, its orbit will take it very close to the Sun repeatedly. Eventually it will lose control due to lower fuel and the entire spacecraft will be heated to a more then high enough value to sterilize anything.

Most likely they will simply continue to do as many close passes as it can. If they can get a closer approach then they will try it. If they can't, it will basically melt except for the heat shield and a few other components, and might end up in Venus or the Sun.

Comment: Hopefully it'll hit the sun, it would be our first addition to the suns mass in human history :). Negligible, but still cool.

Comment: That isn't really that likely. I suppose it could happen eventually, but... A very close approach would be required.

Comment: "If they can get a closer approach then they will try it." This is purely speculation, right? I mean I can write "Even if they can get a closer approach they wouldn't risk it, but instead keep it alive as long as possible to continue to collect data" and it would be equally valid, wouldn't it? Is there a source somewhere?

Comment: Source: Almost every single NASA mission always takes a conservative approach first, with a plan to do a more risky high science value after the primary mission is done. I could list a dozen or more missions that this has been done. The logical step for PSP is to try and do a closer approach, if they can figure out how to make it happen. I know that they wanted to get PSP closer, but something was holding it back.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto "Deorbiting" is roughly as hard as escaping the sun's gravitational pull; orbits (like Earth's) are roughly in the midpoint between "fall into sun" and "escape sun's gravity pull".  So it could be as simple as lacking fuel to get closer to the sun...

Comment: Full deorbiting is actually harder, but it will be close enough that it could be possible, but only if it is close enough to the Sun that the atmosphere actually drags the spacecraft. I suspect, however, that it would melt before that occurs, and essentially be come a part of the solar wind.

Comment: Incrementally closer is what they're doing with the PSP as is.  Only the last 3 of the 24 planned approaches will be after the 7th and final planned Venus flyby that puts in in the tightest orbit.  https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/95/Velocity_of_Parker_Solar_Probe_wide.svg/800px-Velocity_of_Parker_Solar_Probe_wide.svg.png

Comment: @Yakk: *""Deorbiting" is roughly as hard ..."* Not really. It would only require a tiny adjustment to any of the Venus fly-bys to put the probe into an orbit that intersects the sun.

Comment: @DaveTweed You mean by slingshotting?  Sure, but slingshotting out of the solar system is just as easy as into the sun.  And by easy, I mean takes really careful aim and timing.  Is the polar orbiter planning on visiting Venus many many times?  Then they could sun-dive after a safe "near visit".  If they don't visit Venus (or another body) after swinging near the sun, it would be exceedingly hard to hit the sun.

Comment: @Yakk: Not really. The orbit is highly elliptical. It wouldn't take all that much at AP to drive PE to 0.

Comment: I was playing around woth universe simulator 2. In 2075 the orbit of parker always seems to circularize below mercury's orbit. I dont know how realistic that is though. Seems to happen after venus wiggles its inclination over 40 years.

Comment: I don't think the orbital dynamics of Universe Simulator 2 are really that accurate...